# Multi-value field storage limit on IBM Domino

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have a Domino Form and i was thinking of keeping a log in a multi-value field.
For example

> User Foo Bar created a new Item on 1/2/2015

I am wondering what is the storage limit of a multi-value field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit varies a bit based on whether or not you have the `SUMMARY` flag enabled for the field, and gets a bit complicated if you do. The general rule of thumb is about 32k per field, with variations and limits based on the summary state. You can go much higher if you store it as Rich Text or MIME. I believe that the multi-value delimiter is one byte, and most characters are also one byte.

IBM has a table of limits here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTES_AND_DOMINO_KNOWN_LIMITS.html

Warning: do not go above 32k of summary data in a document - there's a decent chance that you will be allowed to save it, but the document will then become unreadable.

Comment: Note that DominoDocument fields are SUMMARY by default. You might want to specifically set it to non-summary. Alternatively, on occasion I've restricted it to, say, 100 entries. Vectors make it easier to add to the start of the Vector and trim to a certain length.

Comment: Agreed. If it can get large, is just to maintain a log and doesn't need to be displayed in views go for a RichText field and use the .appendText() and .addNewLine(1) methods for every entry.

Comment: Also note that if the field is included on a form or subform, then every time you save the document or do a compute-with-form, the field will want go back to summary. it's best to just save non-summary data in an item that is not actually a field on the form, and use a computed text formula to display the data.

Answer (score 3):

The max size of **all** text fields in a document which have set the summary flag is 32K.
The summary flag has to be set if you want to show a field's content in a view.

If you set field's summery flag to false then the limit is 32K per text field.